# How create a function to navigate between text and header?

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode

I tried org-mode, and I'm impressed. My org-file for notes is organized like this:

> Header 1
>
> Sub header 1
>
> ```
>   Foo [ cursor here] 
>
>   Bar
> ```
>
> Sub header 2

Currently I use the function `org-cycle` a lot. It toggles (close or open) the header or the sub header.

But when the cursor is on the text `foo`, then when I call `org-cycle` with a key, the subheader will not close. Only when I move the cursor to the sub header 1.

I tried to figure out how I could come with a function, that `org-cycle` will also work in the text fields under a subheader/header. But I couldn't wrap my head around it...

Any suggestions? It will be appreciated!

Comment: <kbd> Shift Tab </kbd> will close / open all subheadings.  Is that similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it closes the subheaders too, and jumps to the header. I'm looking for the `org-cycle` which also works on the text fields under sub headers. But thanks for the suggestion anyway, it's always appreciated.

Comment: You could use org-backward-heading-same-level, passing in an argument of 0 to move to the heading for the text you're in, then call org-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is already built in to org mode.  You just need to set the following option in your init file:

```
(setq org-cycle-emulate-tab nil)
```

With that setting the `TAB` key should always call `org-cycle` on the current subtree, wherever your cursor happens to be.  There are other possible values for this variable, which give more fine-grained control over when to cycle and when not. See the docs for details.

Comment: Sir, you deserve an upvote! My problem is solved, now the text behaves like a subheader, and I can toggle them now. Many, many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Org-mode is built on top of Outline-mode, so you can use all of the latter's functionality at no additional cost. The functions you want specifically are hide-entry and show-entry.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifity, but I would have one keybinding for when it's a (sub)heading or a text, to toggle them down.
Hide-entry and show-entry are only suitable for text fields, not for headers. So that's why I'm thinking about how wrap this into a function.